# Is there a way to force Load Balancer headers into lowercase?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, devops

On September 30th GCP is going to switch all loadbalanced HTTP(S) headers to be lowercase. Is there a way to switch this over ahead of time to test that the code is ready?

Answer (score 1):

You can test your service by reaching them through loadbalancer with this additional header `x-goog-downcase-all-headers: test`

Comment: To add, you can also use `curl` and send HTTP headers in any format you want for testing.